# Get element by cssSelector in Selenium (Java)

Tags: java, selenium

```
<html>
    <body>    
        <div id="login-box" class="form-box">    
            <form id="frmlogin" class="form" name="frmlogin" method="post">
                <div class="body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="50"     value="dfsf@gmail.com" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                        <span class="red">Please provide a valid email address</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" maxlength="15" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                        <span class="red">Password must not be empty</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to get "Please provide a valid email address" and "Password must not be empty" using `nth-child` in `cssSelector`.

I tried the below snippet:

//Case 2

```
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("");
    String a=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form#frmlogin div.form-group:nth-child(1)>span")).getText();
    System.out.println(a);
    if(a.contains("valid email address"))
    {
        System.out.println("Login test case2 Passed");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Login test case2 Failed");
    }
```

It results in `NoSuchElementFound`.

Comment: The span elements are the 2nd child of the `form-group` element. Try using `.form-group>span:nth-child(2)` as your selector.

Comment: Thank You Mark Rowlands. I tried out with this already but I din't get the output

Answer (score 3):

You can use it by element selector

```
By.cssSelector("input[name=email]")
```

Comment: Specifying more details such as where to change the code and how the changed code helps solve the OP's problem will make the answer more acceptable.

Comment: If you have read question clearly, Sugan has said that "String a=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".form-group>span:nth-child(1)")).getText(); It results in NoSuchElementFound.". I exactly answer that.

Answer (score 1):

Try these codes below:

**1- For returning 'Please provide a valid email address':**

```
String a = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form#frmlogin div.form-group:nth-child(1)>span")).getText();
System.out.println(a);
```

**2- For returning 'Password must not be empty':**

```
String a = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form#frmlogin div.form-group:nth-child(2)>span")).getText();
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: Thank you Subh. Even if I am using the above code Is results in same error

Comment: I have modified the css selector. Please check now @Sugan

Comment: It throws me invalid Selector  org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException

Comment: I think there is a problem with how you are implementing it. Can you please add the relevant code in your question ? Also, more of the html snippet will be helpful too. Because when I run with the existing snippet and my code, it is working fine and returning the expected outputs. @Sugan

Comment: I have given the code and Snippet. I don't know whether I am missing out anything could me help me out

Comment: Got the problem! You have added **xpath** as the locator, instead of **cssSelector**. Please replace the code `String a=driver.findElement(By.xpath("form#frmlogin div.form-group:nth-child(1)>span")).getText();` **WITH** `String a = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form#frmlogin div.form-group:nth-child(1)>span")).getText();` and then check please.

Comment: I have used only cssSelector, I wrongly entered here.

Comment: So, what exception did you get now ? **NoSuchElementException** again?.. And, what is **logVal2a** in your code ?

Comment: Yes I get the same NoSuchElementException. logval2a is variable which I have been used instead of which I changed it as a.

Comment: Which **version of firefox/Chrome and Selenium are you using** ?

Comment: I am using selenium-2.43.1 and Firefox-31.0 and chrome-36.0.1985.125

Comment: **Please add the complete stacktrace of error message that you're getting, in your question so that it will be easier to comprehend where is the problem.** I still can't understand where it is going wrong. Everything is working here, at my end.

Comment: Awesome.. :) if this has helped you, please mark it as an answer @Sugan. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to you could also use XPath selectors which are in my opinion easier to use when you have to select the nth element of something. Try this one:

For E-Mail:

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='form-group'][1]/span")
```

For the password:

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='form-group'][2]/span")
```

But could you also provide the full HTML page you are working with? Maybe the form is inside an iframe and therefore Selenium has problems locating the element

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I tried with this also it shows me the same error. No frames have been used in the HTML page.

Comment: BTW xpath are slower and much slower in IE

Answer (score 0):

You need to add .getText() method in order to get the text inside the  tag.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like `object.getAttribute("innerHTML")`, literally with `"innerHTML"`, like this ?

I had a similar problem getting a text from a span tag